# Apache doesn't see 'Authorization' header was sent via curl

Tags: php, apache, curl, http-headers, authorization

I can't understand where the problem is.
I send the request using curl like this:

```
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer asd421123eda" https://server/example
```

One the server site just for debugging I use

```
 die("header: ".print_r(getallheaders()));
```

And I get the following(ips and hostname were changed by me)

```
Array
(
    [Accept] => */*
    [User-Agent] => curl/7.30.0
    [Connection] => close
    [X-Accel-Internal] => /examp
    [X-Forwarded-For] => 19.13.131.123
    [X-Real-Ip] => 131.41.132.141
    [Host] => host.ht
)
```

And if I put some another header:

```
 curl --header "Authorization1: Bearer" https://serverexample.com
```

I see this header in the headers array

```
 Array
 (
    [Authorization1] => Bearer
    [Accept] => */*
    .....
)
```

It looks like for me that apache is filtering somewhere authoriztion header.
Could you tell why it happens so, and how can I fix it.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are running apache2 as FastCGI. As FastCGI apache can not recognize `Authorization` header. You can use this rewrite rule as a work-around

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```